A p-adic integration involving additive character.
I was studying p-adic integral and I came across an example which is :
\begin{equation}
\int_{p^nZ_p^x} e_p(x) dx = \begin{cases}
p^{-n}(1-p^{-1}),\text{if $n\geq0$}\\
-1, \text{if $n=-1$}\\
0, \text{if $n<-1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, $e_p(x)=e^{-2\pi*i\{x\}}$, where {x}=the fractional part of x in $Q_p$. Now for the proof of $n\geq0$ is clear to me as given:
Since $Z^x_p = Z_p − pZ_p$ it follows, after multiplying by $p^n$, that we may
write $p^nZ^×_p = p^nZ_p − p^{n+1}Z_p$. Consequently, we can split the integral as:
\begin{equation}
\int_{p^nZ_p^x} e_p(x) dx = \int_{p^nZ_p} e_p(x) dx - \int_{p^{n+1}Z_p} e_p(x) dx
\end{equation}
In the first case If n ≥ 0 then $e_p(x) ≡ 1$ and using Haar measures clearly the value of the integral evaluates to $p^{-n}(1-p^{-1})$.The problem comes in the second and the third case where the book quotes the following :
If n = −1, then $e_p$ is non-trivial on $p^nZ_p$ and trivial on $p^{n+1}Z_p$, so the value of the integral is just $0 − μ_{Haar}(Z_p) = −1$. If n < −1, then since $e_p$ is non-trivial in both of the integrals on the right side the integral is just 0 in this case.
My question is that for n=-1 case $e_p$ is non-trivial on $p^nZ_p$, then why is the integral $0$ here?? I mean I am not sure if $e_p(x)$ is a locally constant function in the domain $p^nZ_p$. Definitely, if it is a locally constant function here then its integral will not be zero but then is not a locally constant function here how do we even integrate this?? Because in the textbook before this they said that such integrations are possible only when the function is Locally constant. Please help. Book - Automorphic Rep and L-Func Goldfield hundley page 16.

okk changing it... actually this is my first post so kindly tell me where I need to improve in the writing. thank you.

I am a little confused by your question. For instance, on $1/p + {\mathbb Z}_p \subset p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p$, $e_p$ evaluates to $e^{-2\pi i/p}$, so is locally constant. Is this what you are asking?

yes I think it must be locally constant in some ball so how is integral 0? Also what is that open ball we are integrating on? because by the formula of integration of locally constant functions, it should have been $^{−2/}$.p {because haar measure = p}.

Too long for a comment, but in continuation of above, and in the hopes that I have understood your issue.
The open balls on which $e_p$ is constant are $k/p + {\mathbb Z}_p\subset p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p$ (as in my comment above)  [so there is no problem with the integration], and has different values on each distinct coset. So $e_p$ is a non-constant character - 'character,' because, e.g., $e_p$ is the composition $$ {\mathbb Q}_p \to {\mathbb Q}_p/{\mathbb Z}_p \to {\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}\to {\mathbb R}/{{\mathbb Z}}\to {\mathbb C}^*$$ - so that $\int_{p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p} e_p(x)\,dx =0,$ by general theory.
On the other hand - "by hand:"
Setting $\zeta = e^{-2\pi i/p}$, one has that
$$\int_{p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p}e_p(x) \,dx = \int_{0+{\mathbb Z}_p}1 \,dx + \int_{1/p+{\mathbb Z}_p} \zeta\,dx + \int_{2/p+{\mathbb Z}_p} \zeta^2\,dx +\cdots +\int_{{(p-1)}/p+{\mathbb Z}_p} \zeta^{p-1}\,dx.$$
By (additive) translation invariance of $dx$,
$$ \int_{p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p}e_p(x) \,dx =\int_{{\mathbb Z}_p}(1 + \zeta +\cdots + \zeta^{p-1}) \,dx.$$
The integrand is zero, so the integral is zero.

Ok, so I understand that you gave two methods to evaluate. The second "by hand" method which I understand that since the balls of the form /+ℤ where $0<=k<p$ are compact disjoint sets whose union is $p^{-1}$ℤ. So the integration is the one you have shown but you forgot to multiply each of the individual integrals with the Haar measure which is p here but still taking p common we still get the integral 0. Understood. But now the first method where you said that $e_p$ is non-constant character is not clear and also that chain of homomorphisms you took is also did not understand.

Rereading, I don't think that I forgot to multiply anything by anything... Look at it again? I'm "pretty sure" that I'm right.  Meanwhile, best wishes!

Ohkk yes my bad you are right

OK - $e_p$ is NOT constant on the whole group $p^{-1}{\mathbb Z}_p$ because it takes $p$ different values, the $\zeta^k$ in the above. Is that clear?

On the other hand, $e_p$ is locally constant, e.g., it is constant on $k/p + {\mathbb Z}_p$.

As for your question about the nature of that chain of homomorphisms... Is it clear to you that $\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p$ is canonically isomorphic (equal!) to $({\mathbb Q} / {\mathbb Z}){(p)}$, where $A{(p)}$ denotes the part of an abelian $A$ group where each element is killed by some power of $p$? Then, $${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z} = \oplus_p ({\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z} )_{(p)}.$$ This is the 'partial fractions of cal one,' but for the rationals.

could you please explain why ℚ/ℤ is canonically isomorphic to (ℚ/ℤ)()? your other comments before this on the second method is totally clear to me.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

${\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb Z}l$ and ${\mathbb Q}\to {\mathbb Q_l}$ induce ${\mathbb Q} /{\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Q_l}/{\mathbb Z_l}.$R An arbitrary element of rhs is of the form $l^{-n}(a_0 + la_1+\cdots + l^{n-1}a{n-1})  + {\mathbb Z}l$ ($a_k$ integers); conversely an arbitrary element of $({\mathbb Q} /{\mathbb Z}){(l)}$ is represented  by an element of ${\mathbb Q}$ with only powers of $l$ in the denominator, e.g., of the form $l^{-n}(a_0+la_1+\cdots + l^{n-1}a_{n-1})$... Loosely! BTW this is getting a bit long! You might have been better off talking to someone ...

I see you saw the previous - I had to delete and repost because one is not allowed to edit a comment after five minutes. A v. good reason not to have 'explanations' in comments

and I just edited the penultimate - again! reload please
